# Do I need an SD card to add apps to an Advent Amico Android Tablet?

Tags: applications, external-sd, usb-connection-mode, advent-amico

The **Advent Amico Android Tablet PC arrives without an SD card**, and has 487Mb of internal ROM available.  Plenty for a few apps surely?

There is **no Android marketplace** or alternative marketplace app visible on the tablet to get new apps from.  The nearest thing is **PK Manager**.  That offers an option to install apks from a micro SD card.  It doesn't offer an option to install from internal ROM.

I can **upload files to a limited area of the internal ROM** using USB, with USB set for mass storage, using either Windows file explorer or 'Amico Transfer Companion'.  So far this doesn't appear to be very useful as besides not being able to install from this limited area, none of the pre-installed apps see the files I put there, even when configured to use internal ROM!  Putting apks in the top level of this directory does not install them.

I don't seem to be able to use the tablet for app development either, without an HD card.  I'd need to use the USB in ADB mode, (and on Win 7) I **need a USB driver which does not appear to be available**.  The support site, [http://support.thetechguys.com/amico][1] doesn't have any support and just says 'coming soon'.

**So without an SD card is there no way to add new apps?**  Is there some setting or method to do this that I'm overlooking?

**EDIT:**

I've now found that the USB uploaded files not appearing when viewed from the tablet was down to me looking for them with USB still connected.  Once the tablet is free floating again, not USB'ed to the PC, the tablet can see the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try emailing them to yourself or downloading them from somewhere (Dropbox public link or a web host of some sort). On most (if not all?) devices you can just launch an .apk after it's been downloaded and it will open with the application installer.

You'd most likely also need to allow "Unknown Sources" for this to work, which should be found in the settings menu under `Settings->Applications->Unknown sources`.

Comment: Thanks.  Unknown Sources was enabled.  Once I'd disconnected the USB the uploaded .apk file became visible.  PK Manager only offered install from SD, but using IFileManager instead and looking under 'LocalDisk' clicking on the .apk installed it.  Problem solved.